# Verify 'X' number of digits have been inputted in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, user-input, verify

Writing a batch script.  How can I verify '3' NUMERIC digits have been inputted by a user with the "/p" prompt?

Prompt to user:

```
SET /P SITEID=ENTER SITE # (i.e. 001 - MUST BE 3 DIGITS):
```

I need to verify 3 digits have been inputted, if good continue with script. If NOT good re-prompt user to message of my choosing.

Comment: I went with a post that was originally put up then removed for unknown reasons cause it works:

SET /P SITEID=ENTER SITE # (i.e. 001 - MUST BE 3 DIGITS): 

SET test=1%SITEID%
IF %test% GTR 1000 IF %test% LEQ 1999 GOTO OK

Comment: this would consider `yes` as valid. because it compares strings, and `1yes` is greater than `1000` and less than `1999` (btw: it would consider `999` as invalid, `geq` fits better than `gtr`)

Comment: @Stephan: bullshit. `1yes` is greater than `1999` ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "Input="
:Prompt
set /p "Input=ENTER SITE # (i.e. 001 - MUST BE 3 DIGITS): "
if not defined Input goto Prompt
set "Input=%Input:"=%"
for /f "delims=0123456789" %%A in ("%Input%") do goto Prompt
for /f "tokens=1* delims=0" %%A in ("10%Input%") do set "Input=%%B"
if %Input%0 geq 10000 goto Prompt
set "Input=000%Input%"
set "Input=%Input:~-3%"
echo Success = %Input%
pause
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

Script Explanation:

- Prompt for Input
- Validate Input
- Remove Poison Quotation Characters
- Verify Input is only Numbers
- Remove leading 0's for comparison
- Verify Input is less than 1000
- Add back leading 0's
- Display Success
- If any validation fails, the user is prompted again

Update:

- Fix leading 0 removal
- Add example of how to add back leading 0's

Comment: "Remove leading 0's": sadly not only leading zeros. For example `102` will lead to  `1`

Comment: @Stephan. Thanks should be fixed now.

Comment: Now it works :)  And adding forgotten leading zeros is a nice bonus to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
:loop
    SET /P "SITEID=ENTER SITE # (i.e. 001 - MUST BE 3 DIGITS):"
    echo("%SITEID:"= %"|findstr /rbe /c:"""[0-9][0-9][0-9]""" >nul || ( echo FAIL & goto loop )
```

It takes the `%SITEID%` variable, removes quotes if present and send the data into `findstr` to test against a regular expression (`/r` switch) : at the begining of data (`/b` switch) initial quote (from the `echo` command) three numeric characters, a closing quote (from the `echo` command) and end of string (`/e` switch). If the `findstr` does not found a match, errorlevel is set and the code after `||` is executed, printing a message to console an returning to the `:loop` label to ask again.